# Consume RabbitMQ Dead letter queue messages

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, event-bus

I have read about RabbitMQ & it's techniques on handling the events which fail to process at consumers (not acknowledged messages, expired ttl-s etc.). [RabbitMQ DLX](http://%20https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html)

The way this is working (as I understand) is setting a Dead Letter Exchange to the processing queue.
So far so good, when the events are failing I can see that the Dead letter queue is getting it's messages saved there.

But how do I consume these messages saved there ?!
In my case I want to re-process them after their TTL in **dlq** has expired, but in .NET Core (C#), I couldn't find a way or an implementation how to achieve this.
I could also agree with other solutions like creating a background worker to check for dead-messages etc.

Can this be achieved ? If yes, please help me understand what I need to do to get this working

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure a "dead letter queue" to handle messages that have been rejected or undelivered. Using the RabbitMQ Client library, you can bind a consumer to that configured queue and retrieve the messages from it. From there you decide in code what you want to do to reprocess/reject them completely.

I've found a useful step by step guide for you to follow with more detail: https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/dead-letter-exchanges-at-rabbitmq-net-core-b6348122460d

Comment: I used that exact article and it leaves you off exactly where he and also I are having the issue. It shows you how to set up and configure a dead letter exchange and queue but not how to reprocess the items in that queue.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider attaching the original q's source exchange as the DL exchange of the dlq, which makes the original q and the dlq the DLQs to each other, forming a re-try loop.

The added dlq serves as a temp store of retry messages, and a retry delay buffer with the TTL mechanism. Messages timing out in the dlq get auto-pushed back to the original q for retry. The original q's consumer handles both first-time and retry messages.

To avoid an infinite loop of retries, a retry counter would be set in the message; and the consumer of the original q needs to eventually break the retry loop based on that counter.

Comment: This approach defeats the idea of DLX, since for this workflow you can just NACK with `requeue` flag set to `true`.

Comment: There are quite some different things you can do with DLQ than just NACK: offending message goes to the tail of the original q instead of head; dynamic/exponential TTL to control the retry pace; external report/storage of the retry/error status....